# Exponential map of Beltrami-Klein model of hyperbolic geometry

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, noneuclidean-geometry

In the [Betrami-Klein model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model) of hyperbolic geometry, geodesics are represented as straight lines. Hence the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)) of a tangent vector $\mathbf{v}$ at a point $\mathbf{p}$ is $\mathbf{p} + \lambda \mathbf{v}$, where $\lambda$ is a scalar that depends on $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. For example, suppose $\mathbf{p} = 0$. Then [the exponential map is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model#Distance_formula)

$$ \exp_\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{v}) = \hat{\mathbf{v}} \tanh \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert $$

Notice that $\tanh \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert < 1$ always, since we cannot reach the circle at infinity with any finite $\mathbf{v}$.

Now consider the diagram below:

[image]

where $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{p} + \lambda \mathbf{v}$. The hyperbolic distance between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ must be equal to the length of the tangent vector, that is, $d(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}) = \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert$. This hyperbolic distance is

$$ d(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}) = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\lvert\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{r_1}\rvert \lvert\mathbf{q} - \mathbf{r_2}\rvert}{\lvert\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{r_2}\rvert \lvert\mathbf{q} - \mathbf{r_1}\rvert}$$

where $\mathbf{r_1}$ and $\mathbf{r_2}$ are the two [ideal points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_point) intersected by the straight line connecting $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$. We can find these ideal points as follows:

\begin{align}
1 &= \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r} \\
&= (\mathbf{p} + \mu \mathbf{v}) \cdot (\mathbf{p} + \mu \mathbf{v}) \\
&= \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{p} + 2 \mu \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{v} + \mu^2 \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} 
\end{align}

Hence

\begin{align}
\mu &= \frac{-2 \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{v} \pm \sqrt{(2 \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{v})^2 - 4 (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v})(\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{p} - 1)}}{2 \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}} \\
&= \frac{-\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{v} \pm \sqrt{(\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{v})^2 - (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}) (\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{p} - 1)}}{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}}
\end{align}

so that $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{p} + \mu \mathbf{v}$ for each root. Hence we have

\begin{align}
\lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert &= \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\lvert\mathbf{p} - (\mathbf{p} + \mu_1 \mathbf{v})\rvert \lvert(\mathbf{p} + \lambda \mathbf{v}) - (\mathbf{p} + \mu_2 \mathbf{v})\rvert}{\lvert\mathbf{p} - (\mathbf{p} + \mu_2 \mathbf{v})\rvert \lvert(\mathbf{p} + \lambda \mathbf{v}) - (\mathbf{p} + \mu_1 \mathbf{v})\rvert}
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\lvert\mu_1 \mathbf{v}\rvert \lvert(\lambda - \mu_2) \mathbf{v}\rvert}{\lvert\mu_2 \mathbf{v}\rvert \lvert(\lambda - \mu_1) \mathbf{v}\rvert}
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\lvert\mu_1\rvert \lvert\lambda - \mu_2\rvert}{\lvert\mu_2\rvert \lvert\lambda - \mu_1\rvert}
\end{align}

or equivalently

\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{\lambda - \mu_2}{\lambda - \mu_1} \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert}
\\
\frac{\lambda - \mu_2}{\lambda - \mu_1} = \pm \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert}
\\
\lambda - \mu_2 = \pm \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert} (\lambda - \mu_1)
\\
\lambda \left( 1 \mp \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert} \right) = \mu_2 \mp \mu_1 \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert}
\\
\lambda = \frac{\mu_2 \mp \mu_1 \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert}}{1 \mp \left\lvert \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1} \right\rvert \mathrm{e}^{2 \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert}}
\end{align}

We pick the root $\lambda > 0$. Is this result correct? Can it be simplified? Can anyone find a source for it?

Comment: I think your calculation of the ideal points does not work the mu can be further simplified and r becomes plus min 1 and almost meaningless

Comment: @Willemien Why does it become plus minus 1?

Comment: Just calculate $\mu$ , $r_1$ and $r_2$  but maybe I made a mistake will work it out in the weekend

Answer (score 1):

The hyperbolic plane doesn't have a center. However, the Klein model does. Because of the isotropy of the hyperbolic plane we can do our calculations from the center of the model. All the results will be the same. Let $p=(0,0)$ and let $\|v\|$ be arbitrary, and let $v$ be originated at $p$ (see the blue vector). $r=p+\lambda v$ is the red vector. We can replace the vectors by their lengths in this setup.

[image]

I would be surprised if the answer wouldn't be $\lambda=\pm1$.

**EDITED**

I guess, I understand the question now. Let $v$ be the Euclidean distance of a point from the origin in the Klein model. Also, let $\lambda$ be a real variable. We are looking for a $\lambda$ for which the hyperbolic distance of the point at $\lambda v$ equals $v$.

The hyperbolic distance (from the origin) of the point at $\lambda v$ is [$\operatorname {atanh} (\lambda v)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model#Distance_formula). And we are looking for a $\lambda$ for which

$$\operatorname {atanh} (\lambda v)=v.$$

Take the $\operatorname {tanh}$ of both sides. We have now

$$\lambda =\pm\frac{\operatorname {tanh}(v)}v.$$

Comment: @Carlos: Then I don't understand the question. Do we not want that $d(p,q)$ be $\|v\|$? $d(0,q)=d(0,\lambda v)=d(0,v)$ So $\lambda=1$. What's wrong with this argumentation?

Comment: $\lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert = d(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}) \neq \lvert \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q} \rvert$. $\lvert \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q} \rvert$ is the distance in the ambient Euclidean space we are using to model the hyperbolic plane, whereas $d(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q})$ is the distance *inside* the hyperbolic plane itself. $d(0, q) = d(0, \lambda v)$, but $d(0, \lambda v) \neq d(0, v)$.

Comment: Think of it this way: The ambient distance (from the origin) to any point on the circle is unity, but the *hyperbolic* distance to that same point is infinity. We are representing the entire hyperbolic plane on the interior of the circle, whereas the boundary is infinitely far away.

Comment: @Carlos: I edited my answer.

Comment: That works. $\lambda = \frac{\tanh \lvert v \rvert}{\lvert v \rvert}$ so $\exp_p(v) = \hat{v} \tanh \lvert v \rvert$. What if $p \neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

I did some calculation and so and if

$P =  (p_x,p_y)$ and $Q=(p_x+v_x,p_y+v_y)$ are two points on a chord the ideal points (points on the unit circle are:

$$I_1 = \left ( \frac{v_y \  c + v_x \sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2 -c^2}}
{v_x^2 +v_y^2} \ , \
 \frac{-v_x \ c  + v_y \sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2 -c^2} }{v_x^2 +v_y^2} \right) $$

$$I_2 = \left ( \frac{v_y \  c - v_x \sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2 -c^2}}
{v_x^2 +v_y^2} \ , \
 \frac{-v_x \ c  - v_y \sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2 -c^2} }{v_x^2 +v_y^2} \right) $$

with $ c =p_x v_y - v_x p_y $

I don't know if this will help you and also I don't know how to write this as a formula of complex numbers (but will make a seperate question for that :)